# DOMParser.parseString comments out and mess CDATA inside HTML string

Tags: javascript, html, domparser

After parsing HTML string with DOMParser, the parser does some strange modification to CDATA included in the string. The only thing I want is to create HTML Dom object so I can access nodes. Any tip on how to avoid changes to CDATA?

**Before parsing:**

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"html\"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/5.8.14/css/aui.css\" media=\"all\"><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/5.8.14/css/aui-experimental.css\" media=\"all\">]]></ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>
```

**After parsing:**

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html"><ac:plain-text-body><!--[CDATA[<link rel="stylesheet" href="//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/5.8.14/css/aui.css" media="all"--><link rel="stylesheet" href="//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/5.8.14/css/aui-experimental.css" media="all">]]&gt;</ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>
```

**Running code example:**

```js
var htmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString("<ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"html\"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/5.8.14/css/aui.css\" media=\"all\"><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/5.8.14/css/aui-experimental.css\" media=\"all\">]]></ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>", "text/html");

$("#output").text(htmlDoc.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```